# Windows Login Application

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapi

I develop a windows desktop login application, written in C#, idea behind making this was that, when i right clik any file in windows, the right click menu should show a login app item, by clicking this menu option, it should lock that file. When we try to open this file, it should show that login screen to open file.
Help me to find the easiest way to do this.[snapshot of login screen is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcM7w.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need three things:

1. A context menu entry within the explorer. This can quite easily be done within C# by using e.g. [SharpShell](https://sharpshell.codeplex.com).
2. The context menu entry starts a program (maybe a windows forms, without showing a form to make it invisible) which will write somewhere a hint (full path of file) that this file has been locked.
3. A [File System Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn641617) that reads these hints and blocks the access to the file, till it has been unlocked.

The third point is by far the hardest one. You cannot do it in C# and your code must really be hardened against all possibilities of evil inputs. Otherwise you maybe allow to execute code with system privileges or produce blue screens, cause you are here at a very low level of the system.

So first think about a concept how and where to store informations about which files have been locked. How can the windows application add and remove entries there? How can the low level module read informations from there? Think about race conditions, cause both are running asynchronously. If you have a solid concept there and the filter works flawlessly, the rest is just nearly nothing.

Comment: Probably offtop. About File System Filter is not quite right: at least exists pre-build FUSE kernel driver for Windows with working c# binding for library. I tried it 2 hours ago, was not very stable (am speaking even not about .NET binding about driver itself, got number of BSODs ), but much time has passed, since i tried it